# Is it 'ok' to develop with a DEV database residing on the same SQL server as the live production app?

Tags: sql-server

Sometimes we have upwards to 4-6 people either RDPed looking at data in SQL Management Studio, or hitting the server with LINQpad, Toad, etc from various locations while developing in mostly ASP.NET and Flex with WebOrb. Is this bad? Bad in the sense that we are trying to keep our live production app stable and as lag free as possible for global users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on a  lot of variables.  It's generally better to have them on different servers.  This is really depending on how you use sql server.  If you just have databases, don't use a lot of the management tools, like nightly processes to alter data and other jobs you might be OK.  You are running a real risk of having bleed over code from developing on the dev database to the production one though.  It's safer to have them separated out, especially for the small amount of money needed to create a dev instance of sql server.

Answer (score 7):

i don't think i'd do that. if it was just me, then sure:) but if there's a bunch of people god only knows what queries they might run. we always use a test server for such things.

best regards,
don

Comment: good point - it's just really asking for trouble - sooner or later, *someone* will accidently work on the prod database and drop a table or something.......

Answer (score 5):

Best practice would be separate servers.  Next best, separate instances on same server.  Next best, separate databases on a instance.

However, I wouldn't be letting any developers RDP into a production SQL Server (or production anything), regardless of choice of segregation mechanism.  Use a separate terminal server with tools and everything there.

Answer (score 5):

You can have dev and prod db on the same instance. Just make sure the permission are setup so that developers cannot touch the prod db.  The negative is a long running query in dev will impact prod.
In SQL SERVER 2005 a better solution is to have a dev "instance" and a prod "instance".
Then is someone mis-behaves on the dev instance you and just bring down that insance.
In SQL server 2008 you can setup up CPU usage plans which can help throttle how much resources can be used. You should investigate that.

Answer (score 2):

I find this a poor practice for several reasons:

First suppose one of your devs messes up and does something that ends up taking all of the processing power of your server. Oops prod is down for no good reason.

Second, devs could easliy change the wrong database. Oops prod is down for no good reason. At least you can avoid this by not giving any production rights to devs (which you should be doing anyway as a best practice.)

Third, if the database is the on the same server it has to have a different name, this can make moving things to prod difficult and error prone. I think it also means it will be less likely that you deploy correctly through source controlled scripts. If you choses to copy objects from one database to the other, then you can have issues with that as well. First if there is data in the object already, you may accidentally wipe it out (hope you have a backup) or you may move the new table structure but miss things like the PKs and FKS and default values and triggers and constraints and indexes or the wizard might take much longer to do the move because in the background it is creating and populating a new table and then droping the old and renaming the new one rather than using alter table. Oops prod is down or seriously slowed for no good reason.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to agree with the "separate servers" folks, although with my company we actually do most of our day to day development work on our local machines -- so we have SQL Server installed locally.  This can be a pain, of course, if you're developing reporting or something that needs production data.  In that scenario, developers here usually get a subset of production data exported to work with.

For acceptance testing vs. deployment though, we do use separate instances.

Developers probably shouldn't have production access UNLESS they're also the ones who do application deployments (as can be the case with small teams like the one I'm in).  If you do end up using separate DBs on the same server, I would at least lock down RDP access and grant access to each development DB on an individual basis.  That's how it works here -- I don't have admin rights to any of our servers at this time, and can only admin databases for applications that belong specifically to my team.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how much you value your live service. I know I wouldn't trust me and my fat hands running SQL on the same hardware as a live application.

Even if the application is not business critical, and the app is not data-bound, you can set up a development environment on an unused desktop machine, so why wouldn't you do that instead of take the risk?

Answer (score 0):

The set up I use is typically DEV database on a local instance of SQL Server (Development Version for me, but Express would probably also work), a QA database on a test instance of SQL Server.  In our environment, this is located on a virtual instance of W2K3 -- soon to be W2K8.  Production databases live either on dedicated instances of SQL server or on one of various clustered instances.  We don't mix PROD/QA/DEV at all.  I use RedGate SQL Compare to synchronize schemas between the various systems, including different developer instances of the database.

Comment: Yes we also use RedGate it is great, however we are syncing from one DB to another within one SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

It will be 'OK' as much as the team don't had any administrator privileges over the server (either SQL or Windows), and their user log-ins just grant access to potentially destroy just the development database and it's associated files, having denied access to production databases

Answer (score 0):

For other application testing reasons, we created a copy of our production server (which is a virtual server) on a separate domain. This allowed the Windows Server Name, SQL Serer Name, Database name to be exactly the same (lots of settings on 3rd party apps require this level of configuration to get different processes to work.). Now we can rebuild a test environment by creating an exact virtual image of our production server.

I was sceptical about running SQL Server on a virtual machine, but it has given our small company a lot of flexibility. We like to think our databases are critical, but it is for internal uses and having some down time would just have workers shift their lunch hour.